# How do I pass a list of multiple dataframes into a function that I have defined?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a function in Python that will allow me to pass a list containing multiple dataframes into it, which will then perform the same cleaning methods on all data frames in the list object.

```
import pandas as pd

my_dfs = []

xl_wb_filepath_df1 = input("Enter the path to your file: ")
xl_wb_filepath_df2 = input("Enter the path to your file: ")

df1 = pd.read_excel(xl_wb_filepath_df1, sheet_name= 'Summary')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xl_wb_filepath_df2, sheet_name= 'Summary')
my_dfs.append([df1, df2])

def data_cleaning(df):
    df.replace(regex=r'_95C_XXXX', value='_85C_YYYY', inplace= True)
    df.dropna(axis= 1, how= "all", inplace= True)
    df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0], inplace= True)
    df.drop(df.index[0], inplace= True)
    df.drop(columns= ['NAME_OTHERNAME_85C_YYYY', 'END'], inplace= True)
    df.dropna(axis = 0, how= "all", inplace= True)
    df.set_index("USECASE_LIST_85C_YYYY", inplace= True)
    df.index.names = ["SYS_MODS_85C_YYYY"]

data_cleaning(my_dfs)
```

**This is the Python Exception that I get:**
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

**Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.**

Perhaps a for loop would work, but I was having issues with that too.

Comment: perhaps a for loop would work... and if you ask about the issues you're having we could help :)

Answer (score 0):

A list is iterator and you need to apply your function to items of the list (not the list itself). Built-in map function does that.

```
map(data_cleaning, my_dfs)
```

Also, as mentionned in comments a for loop will do the the job

```
for dataframe in my_dfs:
    data_cleaning(dataframe)
```